# Is it possible to emulate Android on a guest Windows?

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, android-sdk-tools

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 hosting a Windows 8 on VirtualBox. Is it possible to emulate Android on the guest Windows system?

I've been trying for days now and it just opens a blank black window when I press `start` on the AVD! I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my Android SDK installation or it's not possible at all. I suspected that because I know features like HAXM can't be used when Android is run within a guest OS since the guest OS itself is making use of CPU's VT (if available) and it can not be reused by Android's emulator.

Is there anyway I can run the Android SDK in my Ubuntu while I'm coding in Windows?

Comment: I think you guessed well It could be due to HAXM. you should check if there is any good amount of ram shared with your host/virtual window also check your VGA for that

Comment: AFAIK HAXM is not necessary for running Android's emulator. It boosts the performance of the virtual Android but it can also run without it. And as for the memory, I gave 6GB to the guest Windows and 2GB to the virtual Android, even though at the time of start it prompt it can only assign 1536MB as it's too big for my environment! I have no idea why it says that because as I see it in task manager I have 4GB memory left.

Comment: you are right about HAXM , its not necessary but it boost up emulator.but I think its due to VGA